# Angular apply dynamic class to DOM element when one already exists

Tags: angularjs

I have an element:

```
<div class="wrapper" > ... </div>
```

I know I can use angular to apply a class conditionally:

```
<div ng-class="{'wrapper-big': style.big}" > ... </div>
```

But I want to keep a static class and add 'big' using angular.
Desired output:

```
<div class="wrapper big" > ... </div>
```

So the class `big` is what I want to conditionally add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the class and ng-class attributes together.

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-class="{'big': /*CONDITION*/}" > ... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the array syntax of ng-class.

```
e.g.
<div ng-class="[style1, style2, style3]" > ... </div>
```

Here is an example - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass